# Embed a custom Monaco Editor in a Docusaurus website MDX

Tags: javascript, webpack, monaco-editor, docusaurus

I have a website built using [Docusaurus 2](https://v2.docusaurus.io).

Now, I want to embed a [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) to one page, and I will register a language to that Monaco Editor. I can achieve this with `react-monaco-editor`, `monaco-languageclient` and `vscode-languageserver` in a new React website, but I don't know how to add this to Docusaurus.

First, I added those packages to `package.json` of my Docusaurus website, then I tried to make a component `App`, so that I can add `<App />` to a Docusaurus page.

In one file for the component, I have:

```
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
```

In another file for the component, I have:

```
import { MonacoToProtocolConverter, ProtocolToMonacoConverter } from 'monaco-languageclient/lib/monaco-converter';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
import { TextDocument } from "vscode-languageserver";
```

Then I got

```
./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codiconLabel/codicon/codicon.css
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

And

```
./node_modules/vscode-languageserver/lib/files.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/10StudioWebsite/newWebsite/node_modules/vscode-languageserver/lib'
```

[image]

Does anyone know what to do make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the issue here is regarding the CSS being unable to loaded by webpack. You will need to add in CSS loaders for webpack via plugins.

You can try referring to this [Pull Request](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/pull/173/files) on the [Hermes website](https://hermesengine.dev) which adds the Monaco editor to the website and you can try the editor by clicking on "Playground".

Using [`monaco-editor-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin) might be better here because it helps you add the necessary loaders, such as the CSS loader you are missing in your current setup.

Comment: I did not know that we can accept and upvote an answer... just upvoted.